# "Вглубь" или "в глубь"?

Tags: орфография

...осень тайком подкрадывается в_глубь ложбин...

Comment: Если человек пишет сочинение в школе или на вступительном экзамене, то какое может быть "усмотрение автора". Не нужно дразнить гусей.:) Лучше следовать правилу, о котором уже сказал виктор1799, и писать раздельно - "в глубь ложбин". 

Comment: Вы отрицаете существование предлога ВГЛУБЬ?

Answer (score 2):

Наречия, образованные от существительных с пространственно-временным значением (ширь, глубь, даль, начало, век и т.д.)пишутся слитно. Их надо отличать от существительных с предлогами. Обычно в таком случае при существительном имеется пояснительное слово (в даль степи, в глубь моря и т.п.) В данном предложении у существительного "глубь" есть пояснительное слово "ложбин", поэтому надо писать раздельно

Answer (score 1):

Возможны обе формы, причем часто на усмотрение автора.

(1) В глубь  (глубину) ложбин - предлог  В относится к существительному "глубь".
(2) Вглубь ложбин - производный предлог относится к существительному "ложбин".

В текстах можно встретить оба варианта написания подобных выражений, например:

Уникальные для России вечнозелёные деревья и кустарники оттеснены в глубь горных ущелий. 
И наконец, вода, пробившись сквозь породы, продолжает своё путешествие вглубь горного массива.